# What's the difference among '0', '\0' and 0 with sizeof() and strlen()?

Tags: c++, sizeof, strlen

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int pt[4] = {'0','\0',0};
    std::cout<<"size of pt: "<<sizeof(pt)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"strlen of pt: "<<strlen((char*)pt)<<std::endl;
}
```

the result is:

```
size of pt: 16
strlen of pt: 1
```

and when I change  `int pt[4] = {'0','\0',0};` to `int pt[4] = {'\0','0',0};`

the result is

```
size of pt: 16
strlen of pt: 0
```

Why?

Comment: Strings end with a '\0' (null) character. So the first one really has one value, then the string ends, whereas the second has no values. This is just a presumption though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `'0'` is the "ASCII character `0`" and has the value `0x30`.
- `'\0'` is the character representing the value `0` and has the value `0`.
- `0` is just the value `0`.
- `pt` is an array of `4` integers, so its size is 4x the size of an integer on our machine (which is evidently 4), so you get `16`.
- Since `pt` is an array of integers whose first value is `0`, which is `0x30`, that value as an integer is `0x00000030`. When you type cast `pt` to a character pointer, then it looks like a pointer to a character string whose first 3 values are zero. So the `strlen` is `0` (EDIT: because of the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your particular architecture).

Comment: and why in the first example the strlen of pt ： 1

Comment: @denzel_wu If your architecture is of little endian, then the least significant byte (`0x30`) of `pt[0]` is stored in the first byte of array `pt`. Thus, `strlen(pt) == 1`.

Answer (score 1):

`'0'` is a character with the value 48, representing the printable and displayable digit.

`'\0'` and `0` are both the value 0, with the first having a character type and the second being an integer literal.

`sizeof` gives the number of bytes in an object or array. `strlen` counts the number of bytes from the start of an array of `char` to the first byte with the value 0, and does not include the terminating 0. In the case of your example, you have an array of 4 ints, with each int taking 4 bytes; 4*4=16.